# Send emails on gmail with SMTP

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

this is a summary of my application:
    I made this application in c# using windows forms, all went good until I've added a login form (with 2 textbox for email and password) which allows me to login with any emails...so anyone can use this application to send emails.
    So first will show up a login form where I need to type my email and password, and after Login button is pressed, my main form will show up.

This is my code:

Code for Login form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SendEmail.Classes;
namespace SendEmail
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public static string tb1;
        public static string tb2;

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBoxPassword.PasswordChar = '*';
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            tb1 = textBoxEmail.Text;
            tb2 = textBoxPassword.Text;
            if (textBoxEmail != null && textBoxPassword != null)
            {
                //I use email and pass to take string values and put them into my main form, where I need to specify user's username and password
                form1.email = tb1; 
                form1.pass = tb2;
                form1.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for Form1 (main form):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using SendEmail.Classes;

namespace SendEmail
{
    public partial class Form1 : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm 
    {
        User user = new User();
        public string email;
        public string pass;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
        }
        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Error reports
                #region Error Reports
                Regex RX = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");
                if (!RX.IsMatch(textBoxTo.Text))
                {
                    errorProviderEmail.SetError(textBoxTo, "Email format is not correct");
                    return;
                }
                if (textBoxSubject.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    errorProviderEmail.SetError(textBoxSubject, "Enter a subject");
                    return;
                }
                #endregion

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                //System.Net.NetworkCredential auth = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
                mail.To.Add(textBoxTo.Text);
                mail.Subject = textBoxSubject.Text;
                mail.Body = richText.Text;

                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(\*here I need the text from textBoxEmail (Login form) :*/ email, \*here I need the text from textBoxPassword (Login form) */ pass);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                #region Attachments
                Attachment data = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment.Text);
                Attachment data2 = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment2.Text);
                Attachment data3 = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment3.Text);
                mail.Attachments.Add(data);
                mail.Attachments.Add(data2);
                mail.Attachments.Add(data3);
                #endregion

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
                Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void textBoxTo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            errorProviderEmail.Clear();
        }

        private void textBoxSubject_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            errorProviderEmail.Clear();
        }

        private void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxAttachment.Text = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void buttonUpload2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxAttachment2.Text = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void buttonAttachment3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxAttachment3.Text = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I'm making debug, it throws me an exception: "The parameter 'fileName' cannot be an empty string", so I think that my email string didn't take the text from textBoxEmail ...

I hope that I've clearly specified my problem :D It was easier if I could insert pictures with my program.

Comment: Use your debugger. Which line is throwing this error? Why is there an empty string? `fileName` doesn't sound like an email to me, are you sure it's not the lines which attach files to the email which are throwing the error? Do you intend to attach three files every time? If you don't have something in all of your attachment text boxes you will get an error...

Comment: This is my error: {"The parameter 'fileName' cannot be an empty string.\r\nParameter name: fileName"}

Comment: Apparently, one or more of the `textBoxAttachment.Text` vars is empty. You need to check this before creating the `Attachment` objects.

Comment: It isn't mandatory to attach files, I can send email without attachments...

Comment: So use an If() and check on empty before you add the attachment

Comment: Yes but your code attempts to attach three files no matter what. You need to check to see if there is a string available before you try to attach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that one of the `Attachments` fileName is empty string and because of that this exception is thrown.

```
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAttachment.Text.Trim()))
        {
            Attachment data = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment.Text.Trim());
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAttachment2.Text.Trim()))
        {
            Attachment data = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment2.Text.Trim());
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAttachment3.Text.Trim()))
        {
            Attachment data = new Attachment(textBoxAttachment3.Text.Trim());
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);
        }
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: @user3183299 you are welcome, you can accept the answer if helped you ! Good luck with your project :)